# find distance using postcode in google

Tags: excel, vba

I have this VBA script that I have been trying to get it to give me the distance on a click of a button

The sheet name is `inputwks` and I've defined cells named `C_post`, `D_post` and `Miles`.
I was trying to set `C01` in the VBA script to be the value of `C_post` and `C02` to be the value of `D_post` and the distance to be the `Miles`

Sub GetDistance()

```
Dim inputWks As Worksheet
Dim c01 As Range
Dim c02 As Range
Dim Miles As Range
Dim distance As Range

'Set distance = inputWks.Range("Miles")


Set c01 = inputWks.Range("C_post")
Set c02 = inputWks.Range("D_post")
'Set Miles = inputWks.Range("Miles")

Application.EnableEvents = False

'c01 As String, c02 As String) As Double
With inputWks

With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "Get", "http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=d&source=s_d&saddr=" & c01 & "&daddr=" & c02
    .send

Do: DoEvents: Loop Until .readyState = 4

     If InStr(.responseText, "mi</span>") <> 0 Then _
         distance = Val(Split(Split(Split(.responseText, "<div class=""dir-altroute-inner"">")(1), "<span>")(1), "</span>")(0))
    .abort
End With

End With


inputWks.Range("Miles") = distance
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

the original marco looked like this

```
Public Function Getdistance(c01 As String, c02 As String) As Double
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "Get", "http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=d&source=s_d&saddr=" & c01 & "&daddr=" & c02
    .send


Do: DoEvents: Loop Until .readyState = 4

If InStr(.responseText, "mi</span>") <> 0 Then _
    Getdistance = Val(Split(Split(Split(.responseText, "<div class=""dir-altroute-inner"">")(1), "<span>")(1), "</span>")(0))
.abort
End With
End Function
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Function
```

Comment: Not sure what the q is? Have you tried creating a button in Excel and assigning this function to its OnClick event?

Comment: well this was a public function and i was trying to make it in to a button so i added few bits and bobs to it the original macro looked like this

Comment: ummm looks all gibrish

Comment: ill put it up in there

Comment: i just relized something forget to set the worksheet

Comment: This code needs tidying up - please format correctly using proper code blocks then I'll have a look...

Comment: ive done it it was that input= worksheet

Comment: thanks Steve your a star :)

Answer (score 0):

Ive done it here is the answer

Sub GetDistance()

```
Dim inputWks As Worksheet
Dim c01 As Range
Dim c02 As Range
Dim Miles As Range
Dim distance As Long

'Set distance = inputWks.Range("Miles")

Set inputWks = Worksheets("Input")
Set c01 = inputWks.Range("C_post")
Set c02 = inputWks.Range("D_post")
Set Miles = inputWks.Range("Miles")

Application.EnableEvents = False


With inputWks

With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "Get", "http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=d&source=s_d&saddr=" & c01 & "&daddr=" & c02
     .send

Do: DoEvents: Loop Until .readyState = 4

  If InStr(.responseText, "mi</span>") <> 0 Then _
         distance = Val(Split(Split(Split(.responseText, "<div class=""dir-altroute-inner"">")(1), "<span>")(1), "</span>")(0))
     .abort
End With


End With

    Miles = distance
    Application.EnableEvents = True
```

End Sub

Comment: Google has secured its pages all you have to do if you are using this is to add an s after http